# Firefall's tutorial: Is it possible to replay it?

Tags: firefall

So my friend wanted me to play Firefall with him, and I set up a character and burned through the tutorial really quickly, without learning much. It was all good when I was just following him around shooting stuff, I didn't really learn anything about the game or what/how to do things.

So I would like to go back and replay the tutorial, and hopefully learn what the hell it is I'm supposed to be doing. But on the charater select screen and in-game menu there seems to be no option to replay the tutorial (nor create a new character and start again).

Is there a way to replay it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, no. However, it is free to make characters and accounts of Firefall, so it would not be a huge detriment to create a new account and character, playing through the tutorial, then scrapping it or donating it.